# How to make NON RANDOM this EXCEL VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Helo guys. Could someone help me resolve my EXCEL VBA Code. I'm really having trouble on how to make my FLASHCARD appear IN ORDER from Cell A1 down to the last cell. I have this code but it only generates a RANDOM cell or value. How can I make it non random? I know that by using the code RND, it generates randomly. But how about NON RANDOM?

Here's the code:

```
Private Sub NextCard()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim finalTermRow As Integer
finalTermRow = Range("a60000").End(xlUp).Row

Dim possibleRow As Integer
Dim foundTerm As Boolean
foundTerm = False
Dim tries As Integer
tries = 0

Do While foundTerm = False And tries < 1000
    possibleRow = Rnd() * (finalTermRow - 2) + 2

    If Cells(possibleRow, 4).Value = "" Then
        If possibleRow <> previousRow Then
            foundTerm = True
        End If
    End If
    tries = tries + 2
Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

If tries < 1000 Then
    currentRow = possibleRow
    BoxQuestion.Text = Cells(currentRow, 1).Value
    BoxDefinition.Text = ""
    AltBox.Text = ""
Else
    MsgBox ("There are no other cards to go to--you've learned everything else!  Congratulations!  To study all your cards again, click reset.")
End If
End Sub
```

Hope you could help me guys resolve this issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace:

```
tries = 0
Do While foundTerm = False And tries < 1000
  possibleRow = Rnd() * (finalTermRow - 2) + 2
```

with

```
tries = 0
possibleRow=0
Do While foundTerm = False And tries < 1000
   possibleRow = possibleRow + 1
```

Comment: Thanks Gary's Student. I tried the code and it works. But for only 2 cards. How if i've got more cards?